# query to show result with the row no(like serial no)

Tags: ms-access

```
Example Data:

Col1     Col2     Col3
  a        1        x
  a        5        y
  c        8        w 
  d        9        v
```

Result must be

```
Col1     Col2     Col3    Slno
  a        1        x       1
  a        5        y       2
  c        8        w       3
  d        9        v       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query, but col1 has to be unique field

```
SELECT (select sum(1) from tab1 t where t.col1<=t1.col1 ) AS slno, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3  FROM tab1 AS t1;
```

For not unique fields you can use this

1)this code in module

```
Private curNum As Long

Public Function startNum() As Boolean
  curNum = 0
  startNum = True
End Function

Public Function GetNextNum(anyField) As Long
  curNum = curNum + 1
  GetNextNum = curNum
End Function
```

2)this code in query

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, GetNextNum([AnyField]) AS MyCounter
FROM MyTable
WHERE startNum()=True;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the similar requirement, after some research and trials, I got this: -

```
 Update myTbl SET Slno = DCount("Col2","myTbl","Col2<='" & [Col2] & "'")
```

You can use this query, but as you showed col2 should be unique field.